# mixed arrays (text and strings) in a php function

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, text

Im trying to get to grips with php (rather unsuccessfully). I keep getting tripped up on the syntax for defining and calling functions

the code ive written is

```
$alpha = array(1, "alpha");
$beta = array(2, "beta");

function find_best_provider($provider1, $provider2){
    if($provider1 > $provider2){
        return array($provider1[0], $provider1[1]);
    }
    else {
        return array($provider2[0], $provider2[1]);
    }
}

$winner = find_best_provider($alpha, $beta);
echo $winner;
```

**But i keep getting this notice -**
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/find_best_provier_func.php on line 17
Array

Im aware what the problem is but im not quite sure how to solve it, any helps much appreciated !

Comment: `$provider1 > $provider2` that's not how you should compare two arrays

Comment: Show us the whole code of the find_best_provier_func.php file. Looks like the problem not in the code you provided

Comment: @VadimAshikhman of course the problem is here. `$provider1 > $provider2` is not valid checking.

Comment: @BenM you can check whether an array is greater of another array

Comment: It doesn't have the desired output here, hence the code here will always return the `else`...

Comment: It doesnt matter. He keep getting the notice error and he asked about how to solve this error.

Comment: Therefore one way to solve the error is to avoid checking like that, as in my answer...

Comment: Well, strange. I just checked his code and didnt get any notices (any level errors enabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to evaluate the first element in the array, try this:

```
function find_best_provider($provider1, $provider2)
{
    if($provider1[0] > $provider2[0])
    {
        return array($provider1[0], $provider1[1]);
    }
    else 
    {
        return array($provider2[0], $provider2[1]);
    }
}
```